# Dynamic Linking: Class not visible to ClassLoader, but I've tried each one?

Tags: java, dynamic, linker, reloading

Sorry, it's a little bit of code but it is fairly simple so far.

So, I'm trying to perform dynamic class reloading on the fly, as classes are modified and compiled. I've created a JavaSystemCompiler class that is similar to the WatchDir example, except it compiles only once per save of a .java file. I've also created a JavaSystemClassLoader app which performs the task of loading all classes in the project directory, regardless of package (it doesn't yet process jars), along with a ClassLoader class (JSCL_2.java) in order to actually perform the loading and reloading. Everything works up until I try to use the proxy to dynamically link the new class, in this case, RunContinually.java and RunContinuallyI.java. The error I'm getting is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class RunContinuallyImpl is not visible from class loader

I have tried all four combinations of:

```
JavaSystemClassLoader.class.getClassLoader().getParent();
JavaSystemClassLoader.class.getClassLoader();
JSCL_2.class.getClassLoader();
and 
JavaSystemClassLoader.class.getClassLoader().getSystemClassLoader();
```

None of them work.
The compilable .java files are listed below:

```
public interface RunContinuallyI {

    public abstract void printHobby();
}
```

```
public class RunContinuallyImpl extends Thread implements RunContinuallyI {
    public static int runNum = 0;

    public RunContinuallyImpl() {

    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            printHobby();
            try { 
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

            }
        }
    }

    public void printHobby() {
        System.out.println(++runNum + ": Compiling");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RunContinuallyImpl().start();
    }

}
```

```
import ca.tecreations.Global;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.apache.commons.io.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Tim, with starter source from Advanced Java Class Tutorial: A Guide to Class Reloading
 * 
 * https://www.toptal.com/java/java-wizardry-101-a-guide-to-java-class-reloading
 * 
 */
public class JSCL_2 extends ClassLoader {
    private static final String className = JSCL_2.class.getName();
    ClassLoader parent;
    JSCL_2 loader;
    Class<?> _class;
    byte[] data;

    public JSCL_2(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
        this.parent = parent;
        loader = this;
//        System.out.println("Parent           : " + parent.getParent());
//        System.out.println("ParentClassLoader: " + parent.toString());
    }

    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) {
        if (name.startsWith("java.") | name.startsWith("javax.")) {
            try {
                return parent.loadClass(name);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
                System.out.println("Class Not Found: " + name);
            } 
        } else {
            String path = Global.getProjectPath() + name.replace(".",File.separator) + ".class";
            //System.out.println("" + className + ".loadClass : " + path + "," + name);
            data = loadClassData(path);
            if (data != null) {
                try {
                    _class = defineClass(name, data, 0, data.length);
                    resolveClass(_class);
                    return _class;
                } catch (Error e) {
                    System.out.println("Error while resolving: " + name);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        }
        return null; 
    }

    public Class<?> reload(String path, String name) {
        try { 
            new Thread().sleep(2500); 
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted.");
        }       
        System.out.println("" + className + ".reload: " + name);
        data = loadClassData(path); 
        if (data != null) { 
            try {   
                _class = defineClass(name, data, 0, data.length);
                resolveClass(_class); 
                // is this where you use the proxy????
                // or is it better off in JavaSystemClassLoader.java?

                return _class;
            } catch (Error e) {
                System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString());
            } 
        }  
        return null;
    }  

    protected byte[] loadClassData(String path) {
        FileInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(path);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            // So using this package, that shouldn't happend, but anyway
            System.out.println(className + ".loadClassData: File not found: " + path);
        }
        // okay, so load the class
        byte[] data = null;
        try { 
            data = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("IOException: reading class data.");
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

```
import ca.tecreations.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;
import static java.nio.file.LinkOption.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.swing.*;

public class JavaSystemClassLoader extends TFrame implements ActionListener {
    boolean _switch = true; // start with true, switch off, then on
    public static final String className = JavaSystemClassLoader.class.getName();
    public static final long buildNumber = 0L; 
    String classpath;
    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
    JList<String> list = new JList<String>(model);
    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    private WatchService watcher = null;
    private Map<WatchKey,Path> keys = null;
    private boolean trace = false;
    boolean debugDirs = false; 
    List<String> loadedClasses = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<JSCL_2> loaders = new ArrayList<JSCL_2>();
    List<String> unavaiClasses = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ClassLoader parent = JavaSystemClassLoader.class.getClassLoader();


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
        return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory with the WatchService
     */
    private void register(Path dir) {
        WatchKey key = null;
        loadDir(dir.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        try {
            key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            if (trace) System.err.println("Skipping: " + dir.toString());
        }
        if (key != null) {
            Path prev = keys.get(key);
            if (prev == null) {
                if (trace) System.out.format("register: %s\n", dir);
            } else {
                if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
                    if (trace) System.out.format("update: %s -> %s\n", prev, dir);
                    //model.addElement("dir.rename: " + prev + "," + dir);
                }
            }
            keys.put(key, dir);
        } 
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the
     * WatchService.
     */
    private void registerAll(final Path start) {
        // register directory and sub-directories
        File[] roots = start.toFile().listFiles();
        if (roots != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < roots.length;i++) {
                // exclude the one's giving errors

                // watch, this happens on windows 7 at least,
                if (roots[i].isDirectory()) { 
                    if (
                       !roots[i].getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().endsWith("config.msi") &&
                    // now, i like comments in between, so
                       !roots[i].getAbsolutePath().equals("/System/Library/DirectoryServices/DefaultLocalDB/Default")  
                    ) {
                        //so we excluded those, now
                        register(Paths.get(roots[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                        registerAll(Paths.get(roots[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                        //model.addElement(roots[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
     */
    public JavaSystemClassLoader(String classpath) {
        super(className);
        this.classpath = classpath;
        setTitle("Java System Class Loader");
        try {
            watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOE: " + ioe);
        }
        if (getStorage().wasCreated()) {
            setSize(640,480);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
        add(new JScrollPane(list, 
                            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(clear);
        add(panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(clear)) {
            model.removeAllElements();
        }        
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        super.windowClosing(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
     */
    void processEvents() {
        for (;;) {

            // wait for key to be signalled
            WatchKey key;
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                return;
            }

            Path dir = keys.get(key);
            if (dir == null) {
                System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!: " + key.toString());
                continue;
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

                if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                    System.out.println(className + ": KEY: OVERFLOW");
                    continue;
                }

                // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
                WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
                Path name = ev.context();
                Path child = dir.resolve(name);

                // print out event
                //if (child.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".class")) {
                //    System.out.format("%s: %s\n", event.kind().name(), child);
                //}

                // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then
                // register it and its sub-directories 
                if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        registerAll(child);
                    }
                }
                // on create compile. if .java
                if (event.kind().name().equals("ENTRY_CREATE")) {
                    if (Files.isDirectory(child,NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        //if (debugDirs) model.addElement("dir.create: " + child + File.separator);
                    } else { 
                        if (_switch && child.toAbsolutePath().toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".class")) {
                            //model.addElement("file.create: " + child);
                            //model.addElement("Load   : " + child.toString());
                            //System.out.println("Load  : " + child.toString());
                            String className = getClassNameFromClassFilename(Global.getProjectPath(),child.toAbsolutePath().toString());
                            //model.addElement("Class  : " + className);
                            load(child.toString(),className);
                        }    
                    }    
                } else if (event.kind().name().equals("ENTRY_DELETE")) {
                    if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        //model.addElement("dir.delete: " + child + File.separator);
                    } else {
                        if (_switch && child.toString().endsWith(".class")) {
                            System.out.println("Deleted: " + child.toString());
                        }
                    }  
                } else if (event.kind().name().equals("ENTRY_MODIFY")) {
                    if (Files.isDirectory(child,NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        //model.addElement("dir.modify: " + child);
                    } else {
                        if (_switch && child.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".class")) {
                            //model.addElement("Reload: " + child.toString());
                            System.out.println("Reload: " + child.toString());
                            reload(child.toAbsolutePath().toString());       
                        } 
                    }
                } 
                int lastIndex = list.getModel().getSize() - 1;
                if (lastIndex >= 0) {
                    list.ensureIndexIsVisible(lastIndex);
                }

                // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
            }
            boolean valid = key.reset(); 
            if (!valid) {
                keys.remove(key);
                // all directories are inaccessible
                if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            _switch = !_switch; 
        }
    } 

    public String getClassNameFromClassFilename(String classPath, String classFilename) {
        String target = "";
        if (classPath.endsWith(File.separator)) target = classFilename.substring(classPath.length());
        else target = classFilename.substring(classPath.length() + 1);
        target = target.substring(0,target.length() - 6); // remove .class
        target = target.replace(File.separatorChar,'.'); // form filename to class name
        return target;        
    }                                 

    public void printLoaded() {
        java.util.List<String> loaded = loadedClasses.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(int i = 0; i < loaded.size();i++) {
            System.out.println("Loaded     : " + loaded.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void printUnavailable() {
        java.util.List<String> unavailable = unavaiClasses.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
        for(int i = 0; i < unavailable.size();i++) {
            System.out.println("Unavailable: " + unavailable.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // parse arguments
        //if (args.length == 0 || args.length > 2)
        //    usage();
        JavaSystemClassLoader loader = null;
        loader = new JavaSystemClassLoader(Global.getProjectPath());
        long start =  Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        loader.register(Paths.get(Global.getProjectPath()));
        loader.registerAll(Paths.get(Global.getProjectPath()));
        loader.printLoaded();
        loader.printUnavailable();
        long finished = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
        long total = start - finished;
        System.out.println("Memory Consumed: " + getMB(total));
        new RunContinuallyImpl().start();
        loader.processEvents();  
    }  

    public static String getMB(long total) {
        int megabytes = (int)(total / (1000 * 1000));
        return (megabytes + " MB");
    }

    public void loadDir(String path) {
        File[] f = new File(path).listFiles();
        for(int i = 0; i < f.length;i++) {
            if (f[i].isFile() && f[i].getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().endsWith(".class")) {
                load(f[i].getAbsolutePath(),getClassNameFromClassFilename(Global.getProjectPath(),f[i].getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }
    }  

    public void load(String fileName, String name) {
        //System.out.println(className + ".load  : " + fileName + " : " + name);
        //try {
        //    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(className);
        //} catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        //    System.err.println("load  : Class not found: " + className);
        //}

        JSCL_2 loader = new JSCL_2(parent);
        Class<?> _class = null;
        _class = loader.loadClass(name);
        if (_class == null) {
            model.addElement("Load  : null: " + fileName + " , " + name);
            unavaiClasses.add(name);
        } else {
            loadedClasses.add(name);
            loaders.add(loader);
        }
    } 

    public void reload(String fileName) {
        String name = getClassNameFromClassFilename(Global.getProjectPath(),fileName);
        JSCL_2 loader = new JSCL_2(parent);
        Class<?> _class = loader.reload(fileName,name);
        if (_class == null) {
            model.addElement("Reload: null: " + fileName + " , " + name);
            // couldn't/wouldn't do it....


        } else {
            int found = unavaiClasses.indexOf(name);
            if (found == -1) {
                int index = loadedClasses.indexOf(name);
                loaders.set(index, loader);
                model.addElement("Reloaded: " + name); 

                // so is this where I need the proxy?
                InvocationHandler handler = new DynaCodeInvocationHandler(loader);
                Class<?> proxy = (Class<?>) Proxy.newProxyInstance(parent, new Class[] { _class}, handler);
            } else {
                System.err.println("This change necessitates an application restart.");
            }
        } 

    }   
}
```

```
import ca.tecreations.Global;
//import ca.tecreations.apps.viewer.FileViewer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;
import static java.nio.file.LinkOption.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 * Example to watch a directory (or tree) for changes to files.
 * 
 */

public class JavaSystemCompiler extends TFrame implements ActionListener {
    private static boolean _switch = true; // start at true, switch off, then on.
    public static final String className = "JavaSystemCompiler";
    String classpath;
    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
    JList<String> list = new JList<String>(model);
    JButton view = new JButton("View");
    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    private WatchService watcher = null;
    private Map<WatchKey,Path> keys = null;
    private boolean trace = true;
    boolean debugDirs = false; 

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static <T> WatchEvent<T> cast(WatchEvent<?> event) {
        return (WatchEvent<T>)event;
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory with the WatchService
     */
    private void register(Path dir) {
        WatchKey key = null;
        try {
            key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Skipping: " + dir.toString());
        }
        if (key != null) {
            Path prev = keys.get(key);
            if (prev == null) {
                System.out.format("register: %s\n", dir);
            } else {
                if (!dir.equals(prev)) {
                    System.out.format("update: %s -> %s\n", prev, dir);
                    //model.addElement("dir.rename: " + prev + "," + dir);
                }
            }
            keys.put(key, dir);
        } 
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the
     * WatchService.
     */
    private void registerAll(final Path start) {
        // register directory and sub-directories
        File[] roots = start.toFile().listFiles();
        if (roots != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < roots.length;i++) {
                // exclude the one's giving errors

                // watch, this happens on windows 7 at least,
                if (roots[i].isDirectory()) { 
                    if (
                       !roots[i].getAbsolutePath().toLowerCase().endsWith("config.msi") &&
                    // now, i like comments in between, so
                       !roots[i].getAbsolutePath().equals("/System/Library/DirectoryServices/DefaultLocalDB/Default")  
                    ) {
                    //so we excluded that one, now
                        register(Paths.get(roots[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                        registerAll(Paths.get(roots[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                        //model.addElement(roots[i].getAbsolutePath());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    /**
     * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
     */
    public JavaSystemCompiler(String classpath) {
        super(className);
        this.classpath = classpath;
        setTitle("Java System Compiler");
        try { 
            watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            keys = new HashMap<WatchKey,Path>();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOE: " + ioe);
        }

        // enable trace after initial registration
        this.trace = true;
        if (getStorage().wasCreated()) {
            setSize(640,480);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
        add(new JScrollPane(list, 
                            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
                            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(clear);
        panel.add(view);
        add(panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        clear.addActionListener(this);
        view.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(clear)) {
            model.removeAllElements();
        } else if (e.getSource().equals(view)) {
            String s = list.getSelectedValue();
            String filename = s.substring(s.indexOf(":") + 1).trim();
            if (s.startsWith("file")) {
//                if (new File(filename).exists()) new FileViewer(filename);
            }
        }        
    }

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        super.windowClosing(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    /**
     * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
     */
    void processEvents() {
        WatchKey key;
        for (;;) {
            // wait for key to be signalled
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                return;
            }

            Path dir = keys.get(key);
            if (dir == null) {
                System.err.println("WatchKey not recognized!!: " + key.toString());
                continue;
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

                if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                    System.out.println(className + ": KEY: OVERFLOW");
                    continue;
                }

                // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
                WatchEvent<Path> ev = cast(event);
                Path name = ev.context();
                Path child = dir.resolve(name);

                // print out event
                if (child.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java")) {
                    if (_switch) {
                        System.out.format("%s: %s\n", event.kind().name(), child);
                    }
                }
                // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then
                // register it and its sub-directories
                if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        registerAll(child);
                    }
                }
                // on create compile. if .java
                if (event.kind().name().equals("ENTRY_CREATE")) {

                    if (Files.isDirectory(child,NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        //if (debugDirs) model.addElement("dir.create: " + child + File.separator);
                        //register??
                    } else { 
                        if (child.toAbsolutePath().toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java")) {

                            //if (!buildUpdate) {
                                if (_switch) {
                                    //model.addElement("file.create: " + child);
                                    model.addElement("onCreate: " + SystemTool.compile(Global.getProjectPath(),child.toString()));
                                }
                            //}
                        }
                    }
                } else if (event.kind().name().equals("ENTRY_DELETE")) {

                    if (Files.isDirectory(child, NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        //model.addElement("dir.delete: " + child + File.separator);
                    } else {
                        if (child.toString().endsWith(".java")) {
                            if (_switch) {
                                model.addElement("onDelete: " + getDeleteClassFile(child.toString()));
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                } else if (event.kind().name().equals("ENTRY_MODIFY")) {
                    if (Files.isDirectory(child,NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                        //model.addElement("dir.modify: " + child);
                    } else {
                        if (child.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".java")) {
                            //System.out.println("Child: " + child.toString());
                            if (new File(child.toString()).exists()) {
                                if (_switch) {
                                    model.addElement("compile: " + SystemTool.compile(Global.getProjectPath(), child.toString()));
                                }   
                            }  
                        }  
                    }
                } 
                int lastIndex = list.getModel().getSize() - 1;
                if (lastIndex >= 0) {
                    list.ensureIndexIsVisible(lastIndex);
                }
            }
            // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
            boolean valid = key.reset();  
            if (!valid) {
                keys.remove(key);
                // all directories are inaccessible
                if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            } 
            _switch = !_switch; 
        }
    }


    public static String getDeleteClassFile(String filename) {
        //so take the filename and modify to be .class file
        filename = filename.substring(0,filename.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".class";
        new File(filename).delete();
        // return the result of wether it exists or not.
        if (new File(filename).exists()) return filename + ": false";
        else return filename + ": true"; 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // parse arguments
        //if (args.length == 0 || args.length > 2)
        //    usage();
        JavaSystemCompiler compiler = null;
        compiler = new JavaSystemCompiler(Global.getProjectPath());
        compiler.register(Paths.get(Global.getProjectPath()));
        compiler.registerAll(Paths.get(Global.getProjectPath()));
        compiler.processEvents();
    }
}
```

Global.getProjectPath just returns the path the source and .class files are in.

And I guess you'll need org.apache.commons.io.jar, which is available [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi).

Answer (score 0):

What a lot of code to debug!

I think the restriction you are violating is this one from the `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` API docs.

> All of the interface types must be visible by name through the
>   specified class loader. In other words, for class loader `cl` and every
>   interface `i`, the following expression must be true:
>
> `Class.forName(i.getName(), false, cl) == i`

In the line

```
Class<?> proxy = (Class<?>) Proxy.newProxyInstance(parent, new Class[] { _class}, handler);
```

`parent` should be replace by `loader` - the `ClassLoader` that loaded the interface (assuming `_class` is an interface - I've not followed it through).

Comment: Yes a lot of code. However the pinch point is still where you suggested. It's been a long time since I reviewed this. Dynamic reloading still isn't on an open source basis where it just works.  I can't enter a newLine as StackOverfow doesn't permit it. Nevertheless. At any event. Etc.          I Have determined that JRebel is an alternative, however that is $400usd/year. If you can afford it, I recommend it. It would be nice to see HotSwapAgent readily available for personal use. My code is all.... Personal Use, free, Education, Free, Corporate. You pay. How Much? lets talk about that later.$1